# Where can I find every international flight in the world of late?

Tags: transportation, covid19

With COVID-19 grounding mostinternational flights, the list is surely short, especially if restricted to long-haul flights. While https://www.flightradar24.com/blog/charting-the-decline-in-air-traffic-caused-by-covid-19/, the site doesn't seem to have details of the sort I'd like. OpenFlights seems to be even less useful for this purpose.

If I want a list of city pairs for the US, https://thepointsguy.com/news/april-long-haul-routes-american-delta-hawaiian-united-airlines/ largely suffices for April, though I'd have to search those city pairs to get details.

I am especially interested in a list for each day, or at least each week.

Comment: Looks like https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.3737101 may be useful, but still happy to have other resources besides OpenSky

Comment: Cf. https://doi.org/10.1109/BigData50022.2020.9378218